# Cef based application Automation using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium-embedded

Requirement:I want to automate application using selenium which is built using cef and some windows control.to launch the application we need to create shortcut and edit target with the url alone with file location or.Other way to launch the cef application is to pass the url along with the file address on cmd.

Exact issue I am facing is that I am able to tell webdriver to open the cef application using options.setbinary but for some reason webdriver is not accepting the url when I am passing the url using options.addargumnets().

Options.setBinary("my application.exe address");
Options.addArgument("url");

//Initialized driver with options

Comment: I don't know what CEF is but Selenium only automates web browsers, and only those browsers where a driver exists.

Comment: I forgot to update I have resolved this issue, I had to check the development code. when I asked dev to attach remote debugging port while initialising new browser from exe and then I used chromeoptions setexperimentaloptions() property to control already running chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update I have resolved this issue, I had to check the development code. when I asked dev to attach remote debugging port while initialising new browser from exe and then I used chromeoptions setexperimentaloptions() property to control already running chrome browser.